# Cannot load WFS with BBOX Parameters via Python script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, wfs, extents

I tried to load a WFS with BBox-Parameters using a python script. The script is working, but loads the whole layer, instead of just the part inside the set BBox.
The URL itself works on both the Browser and the QGis-Client and loads only the features inside the BBox.
Why isn't the BBox recognized, when using a python script?

Code:

```
url ="https://inspire.brandenburg.de/services/boartsubstr_wfs?version=2.0.0&srsName=EPSG:25833&service=WFS&Request=GetFeature&typename=app:bodenarten&namespace=xmlns(app%3Dhttp://www.deegree.org/app)&BBOX=367808.0001,5844987.0001,378111.0001,5858643.0001"

layer = QgsVectorLayer(url,'Example', 'WFS')

if not boden_layer.isValid():
    print ("Fail")
    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Comment: Can you double check what actual request is sent?  What if you use just `https://inspire.brandenburg.de/services/boartsubstr_wfs?version=2.0.0&service=WFS&Request=GetFeature&typenames=app:bodenarten&BBOX=367808.0001,5844987.0001,378111.0001,5858643.0001&` that returns 66 results for me.

Comment: Is it possible you already have a layer of the same name with all features loaded?

Comment: Both the requests return the same objects (66) and do so everywhere, except when loading it from a python script.

Comment: What you describe though is impossible, either the request is sent with the bounding and server replies with the 66 features, or the request is sent without the bounding box, and you get all (several thousand) features.  It can't be that the server sends 66 features and the client shows thousands.    So either the script isn't working (not sending the correct request) or you somehow have all the features cached and your new request doesn't override the existing data